# R format date with time stamp

Tags: r

I would like to convert the following dates

```
dates <-c(1149318000L, 1151910000L, 1154588400L, 1157266800L, 1159858800L, 1162540800L)
```

into date and time format

I don't know the origin of the date but I know that

> 1146685218 = 2006/05/03 07:00:00

** Update 1 **

I have sorted the unformatted dates and replace the sample above with a friendly sequence but I have real dates. I was thinking of using the the above key as origin, but It does not seem to work.

let

```
 seconds_in_days  <- 3600*24
```

> (dates[2]-dates[1])/seconds_in_days
>
> ```
> ## [1] 30
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know

```
1146685218 = 2006/05/03 07:00:00
```

then just make that the origin

```
dates <- c(1149318000L, 1151910000L, 1154588400L, 1157266800L, 1159858800L, 1162540800L)

orig.int <- 1146685218
orig.date <- as.POSIXct("2006/05/03 07:00:00", format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

as.POSIXct(dates-orig.int, origin=orig.date)
# [1] "2006-06-02 18:19:42 EDT" "2006-07-02 18:19:42 EDT" "2006-08-02 18:19:42 EDT"
# [4] "2006-09-02 18:19:42 EDT" "2006-10-02 18:19:42 EDT" "2006-11-02 18:19:42 EST"
```

This works assuming your "date" values are the number of seconds since a particular date/time which is how `POSIXt` stores it's date/time values.